# Why page Push animation Tabbar moving up in the iPhone X

Tags: ios, ios11, iphone-x

I build a app Demo, use hidesBottomBarWhenPushed hide Tabbar in Push Animation.

[image: Page Relationship]

But, When I click Jump Button Tabbar move up!? like this:
[image: Tabbar Move up]

Comment: for which viewcontroller are you setting `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` ?

Comment: The last ViewController in my first image，and this demo running well in other iPhone device

Comment: and the second screen shot you have posted seems like it is screen shot of your third screen according to first one because it is showing jump button! if you click jump button then you should on last screen and tabbar should not be there

Comment: NO，second screen shot is simulator shot, you can download and see is clear.

Comment: yeah it is from simulator but of which screen ? it is not last screen i think!

Comment: I can sure it, I use storyboard line ViewController.

Comment: I update my screen shot！

Comment: seems like an ios glitch

Comment: Wait iOS release version？

Comment: I have the same issue on iOS 11 iPhone X simulator, but not on other iOS 11 simulators.

Comment: looks like there's a radar open here: http://www.openradar.me/35098813

Answer (score 14):

Answer provided by VoidLess fixes TabBar problems only partially. It fixes layout problems within tabbar, but if you use viewcontroller that hides tabbar, the tabbar is rendered incorrectly during animations (to reproduce it is best 2 have 2 segues - one modal and one push. If you alternate the segues, you can see tabbar being rendered out of place). See the code bellow that fixes both of the problems. Good job apple.

```
class SafeAreaFixTabBar: UITabBar {

var oldSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override func safeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    super.safeAreaInsetsDidChange()

    if oldSafeAreaInsets != safeAreaInsets {
        oldSafeAreaInsets = safeAreaInsets

        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        superview?.setNeedsLayout()
        superview?.layoutSubviews()
    }
}

override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    var size = super.sizeThatFits(size)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let bottomInset = safeAreaInsets.bottom
        if bottomInset > 0 && size.height < 50 && (size.height + bottomInset < 90) {
            size.height += bottomInset
        }
    }
    return size
}

override var frame: CGRect {
    get {
        return super.frame
    }
    set {
        var tmp = newValue
        if let superview = superview, tmp.maxY != 
        superview.frame.height {
            tmp.origin.y = superview.frame.height - tmp.height
        }

        super.frame = tmp
        }
    }
}
}
```

Objective-C code:

```
@implementation VSTabBarFix {
    UIEdgeInsets oldSafeAreaInsets;
}


- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    oldSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}


- (void)safeAreaInsetsDidChange {
    [super safeAreaInsetsDidChange];

    if (!UIEdgeInsetsEqualToEdgeInsets(oldSafeAreaInsets, self.safeAreaInsets)) {
        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];

        if (self.superview) {
            [self.superview setNeedsLayout];
            [self.superview layoutSubviews];
        }
    }
}

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    size = [super sizeThatFits:size];

    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        float bottomInset = self.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
        if (bottomInset > 0 && size.height < 50 && (size.height + bottomInset < 90)) {
            size.height += bottomInset;
        }
    }

    return size;
}


- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self.superview) {
        if (frame.origin.y + frame.size.height != self.superview.frame.size.height) {
            frame.origin.y = self.superview.frame.size.height - frame.size.height;
        }
    }
    [super setFrame:frame];
}


@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works for me. Could you explain how does the hard coded value work in your solution. if (bottomInset > 0 && size.height < 50 && (size.height + bottomInset < 90))

Comment: There's some magic that's out of our control happening with insets and height during animation. The first part of the if fixes the tabbar from sticking to bottom of the view (if I remember correctly). However there's side effect if you have 2 different views that are shown using modal & push segues. Basically if you use swipe back gesture, the tabbar's safe area grows indefinitely unless the 2nd part of if is present (you start swipe back and release it before it triggers & repeat). If I recall correctly only happens if navbar is hidden and if "modal" view was visible before "push" view.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Raimundas! You are my time saviour today! 

Comment: This isn't working for me for iPhone XR, XS and XS Max

Comment: Did you try it with X, cause I really doubt it's something so hardware specific? Maybe it's something in your implementation that's not working. Also given people stopped up-voting my solution, i think this problem should be already fixed by apple itself?

Comment: @RaimundasSakalauskas Its actually an ios12 issue, so don't worry your solution still works for older devices.

Answer (score 9):

This is my way。 Declare a subclass of UITabBar, such as **ActionTabBar**

swift 3,4

```
class ActionTabBar: UITabBar {

    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
            var tmp = newValue
            if let superview = self.superview, tmp.maxY != superview.frame.height {
                tmp.origin.y = superview.frame.height - tmp.height
            }
            super.frame = tmp
        }
    }
}
```

Objective-C

```
@implementation ActionTabbar

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self.superview && CGRectGetMaxY(self.superview.bounds) != CGRectGetMaxY(frame)) {
        frame.origin.y = CGRectGetHeight(self.superview.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(frame);
    }
    [super setFrame:frame];
}

@end
```

Comment: Actually it should be fixed by apple^^

Comment: This solves the problem, but it creates an issue that screws up the Tab Bar frame after doing a modal segue followed up by a push segue: https://imgur.com/a/MIHrF - Does anyone have the same problem

Comment: @chronikum see my answer bellow that solves both of the issues. I also had to add background color view between superview&tableview in my "main view" (that has both those segues present).

Comment: How to use it with UITabBarController? It's tabBar property is readonly.

Comment: @nemissm Set class type in storyboard file.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a subclass of  NavigationController

```
 @implementation XXNavigationController
    - (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
        [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
        CGRect frame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - frame.size.height;
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = frame;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: After the release of **12.1.1**, this issue has been fixed.
You can keep the original structure.

---

If you change your structure from

```
UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController
```

to

```
UINavigationController -> UITabBarController -> UIViewController
```

you will find this issue has been resolved. I really don't know why Apple doesn't fix this issue.

In iOS 12.1, this problem becomes more serious. You can see the TabBar text jump above the TabBar **every time**, if you use gesture to pop back.

**Note:** This way can definitely solve this problem, but I am not sure whether it's a good idea. Also, if your structure is quite complicated, you need to change lots of stuff.

Comment: I do have the same problem in iOS12.1. But does there have another way to fix this?

Comment: Ah, this answer might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53111977/2007403

Answer (score 0):

i'll provide another solution for this bug(seems apple made).

and the solution is not to forbid the tabbar move up , but to make the black area will not show when tabbar move up

the core thing is add a subview to your viewcontroller as it deepest subview and this subview's frame is the window size.so when the tabbar moves up , this subview will shown insteadof black area

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    UIView* bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    bgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    bgView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xefeff4);
    [self.view addSubview:bgView];

}
```

the convenience of this method is you will not have to subclass tabbar or  overwrite navigationcontroller's push method

Answer (score -4):

this problem seems fixed in iOS 11.2

Comment: don't know why downvote my answer... this problem is fixed in iOS11.2 for sure

Answer (score -5):

Just need to add a launch image specifically for iPhone X to asset catalog (because it uses @3x) of size 1125 x 2436.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: How's this gonna help? Did you test it out? Thanks a lot.