# Navigation bar jumps in iPhone X when using Toolbar

Tags: ios, iphone-x

When going from one view to another, that uses a toolbar over the navigation bar, then the navigation bar jumps as seen in the image. Only happens in iPhone X

[image]

I have already added:

```
[self.tableView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever];
```

But that did not help on this issue.

I am not using Storyboards

Comment: You have more problems than that, your tabBar is also wrongly positioned.

Comment: @Shebuka What do you mean with that?

Comment: you can try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232929/why-page-push-animation-tabbar-moving-up-in-the-iphone-x

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar behaviour occur to me when the view controller I was trying to push was not checked for "Use Safe Area Layout Guides". My experiences seems to indicate Apple may change the position of the bottom/top layout guides at runtime if it detects the navigation stacks is using Safe Area layout guides; unfortunately it does produces a virtual artifact.

If you are not using storyboards, you can do it in code.  I recommend this [Safe Area Layout Guide tutorial](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/) for more information on the topic.

[image: Xcode screenshot showing the Safe Area Layout Guides option]

Comment: I do not use Storyboards so this is not possible for me