# TabBar moving up whenever a ViewController is pushed in iPhone X

Tags: ios, tabbar, iphone-x

I've recently added support to iOS 11 on my app and this started happening. Basically, whenever a ViewController is added to the navigation stack the tab bar glitches out during the animation.

It only happens in iPhone X, and this is just a regular TabBarController. What's causing it?

[image: What's going on]

Comment: Have you hidden your status bar in the pushed view controller?

Comment: No, there's no change at the moment of the push, and it happens regardless of what ViewController I push...

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: There's nothing besides  `coordinator.rootViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` and `rootViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(coordinator.rootViewController, animated: true)`, i've even removed every content of the views and it still happen.

I've found someone else with the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232929/why-page-push-animation-tabbar-moving-up-in-the-iphone-x , seems like an iOS glitch.

Comment: Just had the same issue with my app. Even with a plain test-project... I filed a bug-report for Apple...

Comment: I've also filed a bug report with Apple. Please duplicate radar #35098813 http://www.openradar.me/35098813

Comment: @BrunoRocha - Have u solved this problem ? Facing same please help.

Comment: @PankajGupta I haven't, but a new Xcode has come out with "iPhone X simulator improvements", perhaps they fixed it but I haven't downloaded it yet

Answer (score 1):

***Additional answer***

A radar is open about this problem [here](http://www.openradar.me/35098813).

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // Disable tabBar shifts upward whenever a ViewController is pushed on iPhone X rdar://35098813
    BOOL isIPhoneX = ...
    if (isIPhoneX && UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
        [self.tabBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBar.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBar.frame))];
    }
}
```

***Original answer***

I think this is a bug of iOS 11. 
You can remove that weird effect to put down this code to your subclass of `UITabBarController`.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    BOOL isIPhoneX = ...
    if (isIPhoneX && UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
        [self.tabBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 83, 375, 83)];
    }
}
```

The solution is weird, too. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I add some information to understand your 83 magic number :)