# iPhone X not respecting set tab bar hidden animated

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar, iphone-x

I've got a view controller being pushed onto a navigation controller which is inside a tab bar controller. The view controller hidesBottomBarWhenPushed and on view will appear it shows a toolbar. No matter what I try, it won't stop animating the toolbar sliding up / down when the view controller is pushed or popped. This only seems to be an issue on the iPhone X. Does anyone know how work around it?

Comment: This same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232929/why-page-push-animation-tabbar-moving-up-in-the-iphone-x

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47225653/1211917 helps me:

```
    class SafeAreaFixTabBar: UITabBar {

    var oldSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    override func safeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
        super.safeAreaInsetsDidChange()

        if oldSafeAreaInsets != safeAreaInsets {
            oldSafeAreaInsets = safeAreaInsets

            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            superview?.setNeedsLayout()
            superview?.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var size = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let bottomInset = safeAreaInsets.bottom
            if bottomInset > 0 && size.height < 50 && (size.height + bottomInset < 90) {
                size.height += bottomInset
            }
        }
        return size
    }

    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
            var tmp = newValue
            if let superview = superview, tmp.maxY !=
                superview.frame.height {
                tmp.origin.y = superview.frame.height - tmp.height
            }

            super.frame = tmp
        }
    }
}
```