# How can I substitute the UITabBar of UITabBarController programmatically

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I need to use a subclass of the UITabBar for my project because of the following problem [Why page Push animation Tabbar moving up in the iPhone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232929/why-page-push-animation-tabbar-moving-up-in-the-iphone-x).

I do not use storyboards. How can this be done programmatically?

**-- update --**

My CustomTabBarController.swift file now looks like this:

```
import UIKit

@objc class customTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override var tabBar: UITabBar {
        return customTabBar
    }
}
```

And my CustomTabBar.swift file looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class customTabBar: UITabBar {

    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
            var tmp = newValue
            if let superview = superview, tmp.maxY !=
                superview.frame.height {
                tmp.origin.y = superview.frame.height - tmp.height
            }

            super.frame = tmp
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'customTabBar.Type' to return type 'UITabBar'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should create an instance of your custom tab bar and override the tabBar property inside your UITabBarController subclass with it.

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    let customTabBar = CustomTabBar()

    override var tabBar: UITabBar {
        return customTabBar
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives me the following error: Cannot convert return expression of type 'customTabBar.Type' to return type 'UITabBar'. Any ideas?

Comment: I Think that override the Tabbar like didn't work, I used but without any result. Anyone can confirm??

Comment: You have to make sure that your custom tab bar class inherits from `UITabBar`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: My TabBar items all vanished as soon as I apply the override, even by returning UITabBar() itself

Comment: @Bruce Make sure you have the UITabBar instance initialized as a separate variable and return that.

Comment: it doesn't work for example with STTabBar. That tabor works for example when I set it inside storyboard so the problem is with your code.

Answer (score 3):

The only solution that works is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57616340/1837715) by using `setValue(:forKey:)` on the `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Will this have any issues with AppStore submission?

Comment: I don't think so, since it's not a private API.

Comment: tabBar is a readonly property and cannot be modified without overriding tabBar method. `setValue(:forKey:)` directly modifies tabBar property by calling `-[UITabBarController setTabBar:]` which is a private API.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're getting the `'customTabBar.Type'` error is because you're returning the name of your class which, against normal convention, is camel cased. You want to be returning an *object* - an instance of your class - instead.

```swift
import UIKit

@objc class customTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    let myCustomTabBar = customTabBar() // If we're writing conventional swift,
                                        // this should be CustomTabBar()
    
    override var tabBar: UITabBar {
        // Because your class name is customTabBar instead of CustomTabBar,
        // this is returning a TYPE instead of an OBJECT
        // return customTabBar

        // If you wanted to return a new version of a tab bar on every
        // get of this object, you'd use the following code which is similar to yours:
        // return customTabBar()

        // More likely, you want to return the SAME tabBar throughout this object's
        // lifecycle.
        return myCustomTabBar
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for example with STTabBar. That tabor works for example when I set it inside storyboard so the problem is with your code.